# How to format `23/05/2012` into insertable value in DATETIME column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have dates formatted as d/m/y. How can I insert them into a DATETIME column?

Comment: Why woulnd't you use a DATE column for this?

Comment: In the future I plan to insert time too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('26/5/12', '%e/%c/%y'))
```

Comment: I'm inserting into a DATETIME column. I tried using this function but I get 2020 as a year

Comment: @Liso22: You need to use the appropriate format string.  For a four-digit year, use `%Y` instead of `%y`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use php's `date()` function along with `strtotime()` to convert date to any format you want.

MySQL database stores the date in `YY-MM-DD` format for datetime datatype, so if for example you have a date

```
$date = '26/05/2012';
```

You can convert it by using [date()](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://in.php.net/strtotime)

```
$formatDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('26/05/2012'));
```

This will convert the date from `26/05/2012` to `2012-05-26` which then can be inserted into the database.

If you are using a timestamp datatype to store the date in your database, then all you need is to convert the current date into unix timestamp and store in database for example.

```
$date = strtotime('26/05/2012');
//this will convert the date to unix timestamp
```

**Update:**

as pointed out by @wallyk (thank you), strtotime() does not handles `dd/mm/yy` format. the fix is to replace the slash `/` by `-`m below code should work for you.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '26/05/2012')));
```

Comment: I'm getting `1969-12-31` from `23/05/2012` using `$formatDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));`

Comment: it is probably because you have given the wrong date as arguement, can you please post your code. i can fix it.

Comment: `strftime()` does not list dd/mm/yy as a format that it handles.  See the [PHP datetime formats documentation](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).  It can be fixed by using hyphens or tabs, instead of slashes.

Comment: `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('26/05/2012')); // 1969-12-31` I'm not including the variable just copy pasting the code but I get a wrong date.

Comment: @wallyk thank you for pointing that out, @Liso22 you need to replace the `/` with `-` to be able to convert the dateformat. this will work for you. `date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '26/05/2012')));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$mysqldate = date("m/d/y g:i A", $datetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

$date = date('d/m/Y');

$date = strtotime($date); //in unix time stamp format

Answer (score -1):

Basically american date format is `MM/DD/YYYY` and you are providing `DD/MM/YYYY` so thats why `startotime()` returns you a null values on this input; and i prefer you must follow standard date format of american `(MM/DD/YYYY)` because if you are using mentioned format of date that will create more problems as well in different places ..

if you check by this

```
echo date('Y-m-d',  strtotime('05/26/2012') );
```

and it is working fine ..

Answer (score -2):

you could change your DATE column into a String Column and insert the data  when ever you want 2 check if the date is right you can use a regular expression to do so

Comment: -1:  you would be completely side-stepping the power of date handling.  Imagine what it would take for your method to find all rows (for example) between 3 and 6 weeks old.